# Update multiple rows with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I found a lot of similar questions here, but sorry to ask this again because I couldn't get one on how to implement them to the case I have.

here's mine

```
$upd = "UPDATE users SET friend_requests=CONCAT(friend_requests, ' $_GET[user]') WHERE uid='$_SESSION[uid]', ";
$upd = mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());

$upd = "UPDATE users SET friends_waiting=CONCAT(friends_waiting, ' $_SESSION[uid]') WHERE uid='$_GET[user]'";
$upd = mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I update the row in just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
  SET friend_requests=
    CASE
        WHEN uid='$_SESSION[uid]' THEN CONCAT(friend_requests, ' $_GET[user]')    
        ELSE friend_requests
        END,
      friends_waiting=
    CASE 
        WHEN uid='$_GET[user]' THEN CONCAT(friends_waiting, ' $_SESSION[uid]')    
        ELSE friends_waiting
        END
  WHERE uid IN ($_GET[user], $_SESSION[uid])
```

Comment: where does the 'u' came from?

Comment: i just put it as reference. u can remove it.